# Set background-colour of the page outside main container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the [Narrow Jumbotron Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/) example, how would you set the background colour of the content surrounding the page, keeping the main content in the center white. Changing the body background-colour changes everything to that colour, including the navbar.

Basically I just want to change the colour of the two sides, not the content in the middle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `background-color` of the `body` and the `.container` div:

```
body {
    background-color: tomato;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Additionally, to remove the colored lines at the top and bottom of the container, remove the `padding` of the `body` and apply those to the `.container`:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work ...

```
body, html {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```